# Pandas Dataframe subtracting float value from a column

Tags: python, pandas, subtraction, date-math

Is there a way to subtract a constant value from the whole column?

If my dataframe is

[image]

I want to subtract 2.5 from column 1 so that it appears as

[image]

Also, is it possible to convert Date+Time into minutes?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you got your pictures backwards. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: To subtract constant value, I did 
df=df.sub(shift,axis='Distance)
but it gave me invalid syntax

Comment: Did you read what `df.sub` does?  You want either [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) or just `df['some_column'] - some_constant`. You might want to take a read over the [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Comment: I tried this df['some_column'] - some_constant, and it works except i didnt know how to put that back into the dataframe.
df=read_data
df=df['Distance']-2.5
df.to_csv(filename)

I know I am rewrting df so that it only exports the shifted Distance column. How do i not do that? and export the whole dataframe with the shifted Distance

Comment: nvm i got it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If `df` is your dataframe, simply use

```
df.Distance += 2.5
```

for adding a constant, or

```
df.Distance -= 2.5
```

for subtracting it.

(I'm not sure which one of them you want to do.)

Answer (score -3):

using .apply is always a fast way to handle something like this

```
#data.csv is you data
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv('data.csv')

#you want to perform this operation on column 1 that has a label 'A'
#make a function
def col_subtract(row):
    row['A'] = row['A'] - 2.5
    return row

#apply the function to the dataframe
df = df.apply(col_subtract, axis=1)
```

[doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

note: you could also just pass it a lambda function, I just felt it was cleaner to make a formal user defined function with a name to emphasize what you're doing.

Comment: __No!__. Using `apply` is always the _slow_ way to handle something like this. It doesn't even make sense in this context, you're doing the vectorized operation inside the `apply` anyways.

Comment: I just used depth=df['Distance']-62.981. Then to add the depth column to the front of the table: df.insert(0,'Depth',depth)
Thanks!

Also any idea on the time manipulation to minute?